# PHP Pass variable to next page not working

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a variable to next page but i doesn't seem to work as expected. I have done samething on a different page but now it dosen't work.

This is the metod im using to pass the variables (email.php):
`<div class='alternativ'> <td width="50%" style=" padding:5px;"> <form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'> <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='$pidnew2'> <input type="submit" name="submit"> </form></td> </div>`

and in excelimport.php i have this:`$pidnew4 = $_POST['pidnew3'];`

---

Im getting 2 error in excelimport.php:

```
Notice: Undefined index: pidnew3 in D:\home\site\wwwroot\devlopment\excelimport.php on line 77
```

its reffering to this: `$pidnew4 = $_POST['pidnew3'];`

---

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\home\site\wwwroot\devlopment\excelimport.php on line 102
```

and this is reffering to this: `$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);`

---

I have this php (email.php) page that i want to pass to another.:

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions2.php';
include_once 'includes/config.php'; 
error_reporting(-1); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

 //Start av sessions
sec_session_start();
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'Inloggad';
} else {
    $logged = 'utloggad';
}


$uploadedStatus = 0;

if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {
//if there was an error uploading the file
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else {
if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
$storagename = "discussdesk.xlsx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $storagename);
$uploadedStatus = 1;
}
} else {
echo "Ingen fil vald <br />";
}
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kandidater</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.709">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo/wfmini.png">

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checkedbox(element) { 
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (element.checked) {
             for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                 if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                     checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                 }
             }
        } else {
             for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                 console.log(i)
                 if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                     checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    </script>
<script src="js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>

<body class="dashboardadmin">

<ss="container-fluid" style="width:50%;">
  <br>
  <center><h3>Skicka email till kandidater</h3></center>

  <br>
  <p>Välj kandidater</p> 

  <form method="post" action="">
    <?php

    $pidnew2 = $_GET['pidnew'];

    // Retrieve Email from Database
    $getemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Email_Users WHERE pid='".$pidnew2."'");

    if (!$getemail) die('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error());

    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    echo "<thead>
          <tr>
          <th><input type='checkbox' onchange='checkedbox(this)' name='chk'/></th>
          <th>Förnamn</th>
          <th>Efternamn</th>
          <th>Email</th> 
          </tr>
          </thead>";

    if (mysql_num_rows($getemail) == 0) {    
    echo "<tbody><tr><td colspan='3'>No Data Avaialble</td></tr></tbody>";    
    } 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getemail)) {     
        echo "<tbody><tr><td><input value='".$row['Email']."' type='checkbox' name='check[]'/></td>";   
        echo "<td >".$row['fornamn']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['efternamn']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['Email']."</td></tr></tbody>";
    } 
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </form>
    </center>
    <br>
</div>


<table width="600" style="margin:115px auto; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid #eee; padding:10px;">

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">





<tr><td colspan="2" style="font:bold 15px arial; text-align:center; padding:0 0 5px 0;">Ladda upp kandidater</td></tr>

<tr>

<td width="50%" style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Välj fil</td>

<td width="50%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px;"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>

</tr>





<tr>

<td style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Send</td>

<div class='alternativ'>
<td width="50%" style=" padding:5px;">
<form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='$pidnew2'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form></td>
</div>

</tr>

</table>

<?php if($uploadedStatus==1){

header('Location: excelimport.php');

}?>





</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-38304687-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the other one (excelimport.php):

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions2.php';
include_once 'includes/config.php'; 
error_reporting(-1); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

//Start av sessions
sec_session_start();
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'Inloggad';
} else {
    $logged = 'utloggad';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo/wfmini.png">
</head>
<body class="dashboardadmin">
<div class="innehall">


  </div>


<p>




<?php



set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$pidnew4 = $_POST['pidnew3'];



$inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx'; 

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}


$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet


for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
$userfName = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
$usereName = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
$userMobile = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);


$query = "SELECT name FROM Email_Users WHERE fornamn = '".$userfName."' and efternamn '".$usereName."' and email = '".$userMobile."' and pid = '".$pidnew4."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existName = $recResult["fornamn"];
if($existName=="") {
$insertTable= mysql_query("insert into Email_Users (fornamn, efternamn, email, pid) values('".$userfName."', '".$usereName."', '".$userMobile."', '".$pidnew4."');");


$msg = 'Record has been added. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';
} else {
$msg = 'Record already exist. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';
}
}
echo "<div style='font: bold 18px arial,verdana;padding: 45px 0 0 500px;'>".$msg."</div>";

?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the metod im using to pass the variables `<div class='alternativ'>
<td width="50%" style=" padding:5px;">
<form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='$pidnew2'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form></td>
</div>`

Comment: and the 2nd page `$pidnew4 = $_POST['pidnew3'];`

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of the comments and tell us what the issue is. Right now there is no question. "Not working" is not useful. PHP error messages? Console errors?

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks i added more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='$pidnew2'> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

In this form, you mentioned GET method and you are passing variable using GET method in your another page.

You can not get `pidnew3` variable to another page because you are using POST method to get `pidnew3` variable.

You just need to change the below line from

```
$pidnew4 = $_POST['pidnew3'];
```

to

```
$pidnew4 = $_GET['pidnew3'];
```

Comment: Thanks for a replay but that dosent work. I really dont know what I have done wrong. Because Im using the some princible on a other pages without a bigger problem. I think theres something els in my code that reloded the pages and then loses the `pidnew` is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what can be wrong, you didn't display the $pidnew2 value here

```
<form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='$pidnew2'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You should replace that block with

```
<form method='GET' action='excelimport.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pidnew3' value='<?php echo $pidnew2; ?>'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then you get the value of the variable $pidnew2 and not the string '$pidnew2'

Answer (score -2):

You should change the method in the form by POST, as you are trying to get a variable passed through 'GET'. Or as below you can get the variable using the 'GET' method.

```php
$pidnew4 = $_GET['pidnew3'];
```

Comment: @Fredrik Where does $_GET['pidnew'] comes from, it seems to be containing the value pidnew3 should be. If it is empty it explains why your 'pidnew3' index will be undefined as the value won't be sent through the form.

Comment: I really dont know what I have done wrong. Because Im using the some princible on a other pages without a bigger problem. I think theres something els in my code that reloded the pages and then loses the `pidnew` is that possible?